# Trouble to use generic with Enum in Java abstract class

Tags: java, string, generics, enums

I have public abstract class AbstractDevice to extend on some certain Device classes (such as valve, motor, temp sensor etc) which to be controlled by String command, processed as follows:

```
public class Valve extends AbstractDevice {

  protected static enum Mode {OPEN, CLOSE};

  protected Mode mode;

  ...

  protected void processCommand(String command) {

     mode = Enum.valueOf(Mode.class, command);

    switch (mode)

      case OPEN: ...(execute OPEN command)

}
```

and it works correctly.

But when I try to move the String-to-Enum conversion in abstract class to work with any command set:

```
public abstract class AbstractDevice {

static protected <E> E getElement(Class<E> enumType, String elementName) {

  try {

    return Enum.valueOf(enumType, elementName);

  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

    return null;

  }

}
```

I have compilation error `The method valueOf(Class<T>, String) in the type Enum is not applicable for the arguments (Class<E>, String)`

What's wrong here?

Comment: Is that Java? You should add the language to the tags, otherwise people will not see your question. Also, giving properly formatted code increases people's willingness to read it...

Comment: Thanks, tags added, code formatted - it's my first question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Enum.valueOf(Class, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String)) - Returns the enum constant of the specified **enum class** with the specified name.

So change getElement method signature into following

```
static protected <E extends Enum<E>> E getElement(Class<E> enumType, String elementName) {
    try {
        return Enum.valueOf(enumType, elementName);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```